Why is reading bytes here so slow compared to copying the file?
I'm trying to read a whole file's bytes into memory; for now, I'm doing nothing with it.  Reading the file with FileInfo.OpenRead combined with a StreamReader is going very slowly; about 30 seconds as opposed to only 4 seconds to copy/paste the file from one hard drive to another in Explorer.  Why would it be so slow to read it into memory?  The example code:
namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    internal class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string multiGigFile = @"path\to\my\4gb\file";
            FileInfo fi = new(multiGigFile);
            using (StreamReader sr = new(fi.OpenRead())) {
                int bufferSize = 104857600; // 100MB read buffer
                int bytesRead;
                char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
                // Takes ~30 secs to finish the while loop, ~4s to copy from one hard drive to another
                while ((bytesRead = sr.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0) {
                    Console.WriteLine($"File read; read next {bytesRead} bytes...");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"File read; finished.");
            }
        }
    }
}


Whats the reasoning behind using StreamReader here? For what you do here you could directly use read on the FileStream. Depending on the concrete Framework the used StreamReader will put it in its own buffer before then copying it into the buffer you provided here to the read method. And comparing it with direct copy on harddrives most controllers will do it directly without using memory while you presumably use it twice.

The remarks section in the help for StreamReader.Read() might offer a clue.

@Ralf FileStream.Read() reads bytes, not chars.

@MatthewWatson yes but he does not use the buffer.

copy/paste of a file is handled at a much lower level and can offload a chunk of things for example to IO controllers and pure kernel code - it also isn't decoding all the bytes (which you are, because you're forcing it to char data rather than using byte data via Stream; additionally, that buffer is massively over-sized - in most scenarios, a buffer rented from ArrayPool is ideal)

I tried using FileStream.Read directly and it is quite a bit quicker, though still not as fast as a direct copy of the file.

@Jez what are you actually trying to achieve here? if you want the fastest possible access to a large file, MemoryMappedFile might be your friend, but by necessity it has a more complex API

I think it's fast enough for my purposes to use FileStream.Read directly, actually.  Surprising how much overhead the StreamReader adds.

@MarcGravell I figured the buffer was probably oversized, but if I set it to 1024 bytes or something the while loop has to spin a ton of times so I was trying to see if having a larger buffer improved performance.  How large a buffer would you recommend be rented?  As to what I'm trying to achieve, I'm purposely reading every byte from a file to try and detect if there's corruption on the hard drive.

@Jez for this scenario, I'd probably look at MemoryMappedFile, but otherwise... 16KiB? 64Kib? pick a number and profile it

The StreamReader was adding a lot of overhead, converting bytes to chars presumably.  Reading directly from the FileStream sped things up quite a lot.
namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    internal class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int bufferSize = 104857600; // 100MB read buffer
            string multiGigFile = @"path\to\my\4gb\file";
            FileInfo fi = new(multiGigFile);
            using (FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead()) {
                int bytesRead;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0) {
                    Console.WriteLine($"File read; read next {bytesRead} bytes...");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"File read; finished.");
            }
        }
    }
}

